# Save as template not including my site pages SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to move site pages from development server to production Server.

for that I have save site as template.

To verify that,all pages are available in site template.
I have open solution template (.wsp file)  in visual studio, but I don't found any  pages in that.

Please help me with this

Comment: Will you please update your question

Comment: There are a couple of ways to migrate pages. You can package into a solution then deploy the solution in your target farm.

Another way: take a backup of the complete site collection and restore the site collection in the target farm.

Comment: I want to only move my two site pages nothing else.This two site pages already in prod server  we want just update my site page.Please send me steps.This site pages we added webparts.